# BitBucket - non-fast-forward

Tags: git, tortoisehg, bitbucket, tortoisegit

Quite a long explanation of my actions, buckle up. Noob here :)

I'm trying to share my entire project with a few friends and instead of sharing a .zip file around, I thought I'd create a repository. Little did I know about how these worked (I honestly just thought you upload a new version of your file via the browser) and I started with BitBucket. I followed the documentation in BitBucket and cloned my empty repository to

```
C:\Users\Me\repos\name-of-repository
```

However, my actual workspace is in C:\xampp\htdocs\name-of-project

So if I had to make any changes, I'd have to copy my entire working directory and replace it in repository in /repos/. I found this quite annoying and learned how to change the Home directory by modifying the home variable (I did manage to push though! success!). Home is now set to C:\xampp\htdocs\name-of-project. I tried the same method of adding files, committing and finally pushing, but I now face an error as such: https://i.stack.imgur.com/250Rz.png

I've tried adding +develop at the end
I've tried to use --force, but I'm using the correct syntax
I've tried $git pull = nothing happened. 
I've tried $git merge (my working directory is updated compared to ) = No commit specified and merge.defaultToUpstream not set.

I just want to update my remote repository! I'm not at all worried about the fact that it's going to cause problems for others that are modifying the code. I'm the only one, others are following the changes. Nobody is going to fork it either.

Really stuck, any help is appreciated!

TortoiseHg, TortoiseGit aren't exactly working either.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are approaching this problem from the wrong way.

Have you tried initialising your working directory as a git repository?

Once you do this, you can just push your changes onto your bitbucket repository. Merging two repositories is *the* thing about distributed version control.

Bitbucket may also be able to clone your working directory.

e.g.

```
cd working
git init 
set up your .gitignore file (optional, but really recommended)
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push https://bhavyadaiya@bitbucket.org/bhavyadaiya/yourrepositoryname.git master
```

Comment: I agree with everything but the last sentence. Bitbucket won't have remote access to his working directory.

Comment: I forget to add master to the push, but it all works fine. git push will prompt you for the password for the bitbucket repository. This is also presuming you've already created the repository on bitbucket

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and yes I do already have a repository on Bitbucket. I'll try this now :)

Comment: @LukeN I tried your suggestion but unfortunately I still get the same error. I'm guessing I've already initialised my working directory as a git repository? I often see green ticks if I ever browse to the folder to upload a file somewhere. There are .git and other related files.

Comment: That's because your working directory is older that the one on the server/ Insert a git pull url master before the push

Comment: @LukeN Thanks you!! It had some mergine problems and I didn't have a base for tortoisemerge. I then typed in git merge vimdiff and it went on from there. I committed and pushed, it seems to have worked. I think I may have lost some code due to the merge.

Answer (score 0):

Another one has pushed changes into your bitbucket repo. Now your own changes have diverged from the remote branch, so you need to pull those changes into your local repo, and merge this changes with yours.

```
# I assume you use the git bash environment, not the cmd environment

git fetch                  # get the current state of your bb repo
git diff origin/master     # show the differences between your branch and the remote branch
git diff `git merge-base master origin/master`..origin/master # show the differences introduced by the other branch
git diff `git merge-base master origin/master`..master # show your local changes
git merge origin/master    # merge the other branch into your local branch
```